# Angular 2 - Is complex routing a pain point for Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm considering learning Angular2 but I've come across a few hints that routing is a bit of a pain point. Specifically, it appears that complicated URL routing is not handled well with Angular 2. For example, I want to do something like the following:

```
/main/building/[building ID]/overview/ <-- changing the building ID goes to a different building
/main/building/[building ID]/room/[room ID]/ <-- Again, different room ID for different rooms in the same building
/main/building/[building ID/room/[room ID]/tickets/ <-- perhaps a list of tickets for a specific room from a specific building
/main/contacts/ <--- all our contacts
/main/contacts/[contact ID]/ <-- info about that contact
/main/contacts/[contact ID]/invoices/ <-- all the invoices sent to that contact
/main/contacts/[contact ID]/invoices/[invoice ID/ <--- detail of a specific invoice for a specific contact
/vendors/ <--- a list of all our vendors
/vendors/[vendor ID]/details <--- details about that specific vendor
/vendors/[vendor ID/tickets/ <--- all the tickets that *that* vendor has been assigned
```

So, I would want to create a bunch of main categories such as `main` and `main/contacts` and `vendors` that would have further sub-categories such as `main/building/` and `main/contacts`. I'm looking to start a large web application that has about 8 main sections, each section has multiple sub-sections, and each of *those* would have further sub-sections.

Having explored Angular 2 a bit, and specifically looking into routing, it seems (from what I've read) that this is a bit of weak area for Angular 2. Complicated URL maps are a challenge for Angular 2 and, as a result, I've been hesitant to start projects with it.

Am I wrong here? Are complicated URL maps possible? Is it a massive headache or relatively straight forward?

Comment: That doesn't seem like particularly complex routing. Have a look at the module tutorial, which has an example of routing across multiple distinct blocks of functionality: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: Yeah -- not a great example of complex routing. My point is I have an application that has multiple different sections, each with their own routing requirements. I'm not sure if that can all be managed within a single Angular application. I'll take a look at the link you provided - thx